# Matlab: Writing to a file

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, math, for-loop

> I want to store mean_2....mean_8, std_2....std_8, and coVariance as separate columns in a file. Help Please?

This Code calculates IntervalFeatures of Erp signal with 256 time frames
 and plots them
 Datapoints are store in A

___________HowTheCodeWorks________________________________________________

each 1x4 sliding sub-matrix is made a column
 for eg:- if A is 1x6 you would get 1-2-3-4, 2-3-4-5, 3-4-5-6 each as a column
 ending with 3 columns. for 1x10 matrix, you would get 7 columns

calculating the mean of every column

Subtract each value of the column with the mean value of corresponding column
 finally element-wise squaring, mean of each column 
 and then element-wise sqrt to get the output.

```
A=firstElec;

%___________Length2_____________________
reshaped_2 = im2col(A,[1 2],'sliding');
mean_2 = mean(reshaped_2);
out1 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_2,mean_2);
std_2 = sqrt(mean(out1.^2))

%___________Length4_____________________
reshaped_4 = im2col(A,[1 4],'sliding');
mean_4 = mean(reshaped_4);
out2 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_4,mean_4);
std_4 = sqrt(mean(out2.^2))

%___________Length8_____________________
reshaped_8 = im2col(A,[1 8],'sliding');
mean_8 = mean(reshaped_8);
out3 = bsxfun(@minus,reshaped_8,mean_8);
std_8 = sqrt(mean(out3.^2))

%___________CoVariance__________________
begInt = 1;
endInt =256;
l=endInt - begInt + 1;
arrayCovar = zeros(1,257);
j=1;
for k=1:256

coVar = 1/l *((A(k)*k) - (mean(A(k:j))*((begInt + endInt)/2)));
j= 1+k;
arrayCovar(k)=coVar;
end

coVariance = arrayCovar(:,1:256);
disp(coVariance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the matrices to be displayed in each column, that's going to be ugly.  If I'm interpreting your request correctly, you are concatenating row vectors so that they appear as a single row.  That's gonna look pretty bad.

What I would suggest you do is split them up so that each row vector is separated per line.  Use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) for that:

```
dlmwrite('data.txt', mean_2);
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', mean_4, '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', mean_8, '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', std_2, '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', std_4, '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', std_8, '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', ' ', '-append');
dlmwrite('data.txt', coVariance, '-append');
```

Comment: But i want them as columns?

Comment: @HarshSharma - That's going to be ugly.  Each matrix has a different number of rows so I'd have to loop and make some really ugly code.  I suggest using `dlmwrite` and separate each matrix by rows.  See my edit.

Comment: @HarshSharma - However... if you're really hell bent on placing each matrix in separate columns, we can do that.

Comment: It shouldn't. You're writing to file! Check your working directory for a file called data.txt

Answer (score 0):

Convert the vectors to a single cell using the function below (usage `x = Cellify(mean_2, mean_4, mean_8, ...);`) then, use this excellent function ([cell2csv](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47055-cell-array-to-csv-file--improved-cell2csv-m-)) to write to a file.

```
function x = Cellify(varargin)
    maxSize = [0, 0];
    totalSize = [0, 0];

    for i = 1:nargin
        maxSize = max([maxSize; size(varargin{i})]);
        totalSize = sum([totalSize; size(varargin{i})]);
    end

    x = cell(maxSize(1), totalSize(2));

    columnShift = 0;

    for i = 1:nargin
        x(1:size(varargin{i}, 1), 1+columnShift:size(varargin{i}, 2)+columnShift) = num2cell(varargin{i});
        columnShift = size(varargin{i}, 2);
    end
end
```